# NGRX Effects how to pass parameter to withLatestFrom operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am struggling with passing parameter to selector when by using withLatestFrom, which was mapped earlier from load action payload

```
loadLocalSubServices$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServicesTemplateActionTypes.LoadLocalSubService),
  map((action: LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LoadLocalSubService) => action.payload.globalSubServiceId),
  // and below I would like to pass globalSubServiceId
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromLocalSubservices.getSearchParams(globalSubServiceId)))),
  map(searchParams => searchParams[1]),
  mergeMap((params) =>
    this.subServiceService.getLocalSubServices(params).pipe(
      map(localSubServices => (new LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServiceLoadSuccess(localSubServices))),
      catchError(err => of(new LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServiceLoadFail(err)))
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: This is very confusing description. What does/doesn't work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think I have the recipe you (or future wanderers) are looking for. You have to map the initial payload (`of` operator below) to an inner observable so that it can be piped and passed as a param to `withLatestFrom`. Then `mergeMap` will flatten it and you can return it to the next operator as one array with the initial payload as the first value.

```
map(action => action.payload),
mergeMap((id) =>
    of(id).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
            this.store.pipe(select(state => getEntityById(state, id))),
            this.store.pipe(select(state => getWhateverElse(state)))
        )
    ),
    (id, latestStoreData) => latestStoreData
),
switchMap(([id, entity, whateverElse]) => callService(entity))
```

Comment: hi, i think u missed a '(' before id

Comment: @Preda70R can you explain the usage of `mergeMap` and then `switchMap`?

Comment: @obl mergeMap activates all inner observables concurrently, then emits to switchMap, which closes the observable it is subscribed to. MergeMap doesn't have a killswitch.

Comment: This form of mergeMap seems to be deprecated

Comment: @itwasmattgregg what is the new version of this?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use an arrow function.

```js
loadLocalSubServices$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServicesTemplateActionTypes.LoadLocalSubService),
    map((action: LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LoadLocalSubService) => action.payload.globalSubServiceId),
    (globalSubServiceId) => {
        return withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromLocalSubservices.getSearchParams(globalSubServiceId))));
    },
    map(searchParams => searchParams[1]),
    mergeMap((params) =>
      this.subServiceService.getLocalSubServices(params).pipe(
        map(localSubServices => (new LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServiceLoadSuccess(localSubServices))),
        catchError(err => of(new LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LocalSubServiceLoadFail(err)))
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the `concatLatestFrom` to handle this.

Replace:

```
withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromLocalSubservices.getSearchParams(globalSubServiceId)))),
```

with:

```
concatLatestFrom(globalSubServiceId =>
 this.store.pipe(select(fromLocalSubservices.getSearchParams(globalSubServiceId)))
```

https://v11.ngrx.io/api/effects/concatLatestFrom