# How do I use a withLatestFrom in an effect with selector with props (MemoizedSelectorWithProps) coming from the action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a selector with props (of type MemoizedSelectorWithProps). I'd like to use it in an effect inside WithLatestFrom. The thing is - the parameter for the selector (the props) is coming from the action payload. And I can't make the withLatestFrom access the action payload.

I'm using angular 7 (and naturally ngrx7). I've tried using a map to somehow create a new observable, but nothing is working...

these are some demo lines I've wrote here, to simplify my use case:

action:

```js
export const GET_INVENTORY = '[App] Get Inventory';

export class GetInventory implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_INVENTORY;
  constructor (public branchId: number) {} 
}
```

effect:

```js
@Effect()
getInventory$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(GET_INVENTORY)
  withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(getIsStoreInventoryLoaded, {branchId: action.branchId}))), // this is not working obviously, since action is unknown
  switchMap([action, loaded]: [GetInventory, boolean] => {
  if (loaded) {
    console.log('already loaded inventory for this branch', action.branchId);
  } else {
    console.log('never loaded inventory for this branch', action.branchId);
  }
}
```

although this is a simplified version of my code, the design is kinda similar in my real project - I have a store with keys per "branch" inventory. say I'm a chain of supermarkets and each branch has it's own inventory page with lots of data and I want to not-fetch again if I already fetched. So if you have a different approach then working with MemoizedSelectorWithProps - feel free to suggest that too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGRX Effects how to pass parameter to withLatestFrom operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609748/ngrx-effects-how-to-pass-parameter-to-withlatestfrom-operator)

Comment: Can you show your selector

Answer (score 9):

A simple [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) or a [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) with a [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) should do the trick.

For example:

```
@Effect()
getInventory$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(GET_INVENTORY),
  mergeMap(action =>
    combineLatest(
      of(action),
      this.store$.pipe(select(getIsStoreInventoryLoaded, {branchId: action.branchId}))
    )
  ),
  tap(([action, loaded]) => {
    // The rest of your code...
  })
)
```